An $R$-module containing a torsion element cannot be free
This is something I thought of and I want to check if it is correct or not.
The setting: let $R$ be a commutative ring and $M$ an $R$-module. We say $x\in M$ is torsion if there exists a non-zero $r \in R$ such that $rx = 0$ in $M$. We say $M$ is free of finite rank if $M \cong R^n$ for some natural number $n$.
My question: is it true that if $M$ constains a non-zero torsion element, then $M$ cannot be free of finite rank?
My reasoning is as follows: let $x \ne 0$ be such an element, and let $r \in R\setminus 0$ such that $rx = 0$. Suppose for contradiciton that $M$ is free, meaning we may find elements $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ such that $\varphi: R^n \to M: e_i \mapsto x_i$ is an isomorphism. Since it is surjective, we can write $x = \sum_i \alpha_i x_i$. But then $rx = \sum_i r\alpha_i x_i = 0$ so $\varphi$ is no longer injective. Contradiction. Hence, $M$ is not free.
Is this correct? If not, why? If yes, can this be generalized? Thanks!

The ring $R = K[x]/(x^2)$ for any field $K$ has torsion elements (like $x$, for example --- $x \ne 0$ but $x^2 = 0$) but is free as a module over itself of rank one. The argument you make pre-supposes that $r\alpha_i \ne 0$ for all $i$ in order to derive a contradiction, but that need not always hold.

When $R$ is not assumed to be a domain, the definition of torsion is generally taken as "$x \in M$ is torsion if there is a nonzerodivisor $r \in R$ so that $rx=0$." Under this definition the claim you seek does hold.
